# Javascript undefined message when outputting array

Tags: javascript

my first day in JavaScript and I have a thing I do not understand. I have this piece of code:

```
var a = [1, 2, 3, 5, 8];
var b = [];
for(var i=0; i<a.length; i++){
    b.push(a[i]);
}
console.log(b);
```

And the output is:

```
[ 1, 2, 3, 5, 8 ]
=> undefined
```

Would you please explain what that undefined means?

Comment: You're executing this in an interactive console…?

Comment: I don't get the `undefined` part in the Chrome console: https://jsfiddle.net/8zw3w41t/

Comment: If I run this in a regular page I can't reproduce the `undefined`. Worked fine.

Comment: @War10ck I do.  Copy and paste everything in the first snippet.

Comment: @zero298 I did to jsfiddle.net and ran it. I get `Array [5]`

Comment: i use https://repl.it/

Answer (score 5):

You are calling a function console.log and it the function does not retun any value, then it is undefined.

So in this case

console.log displays array b and at the end it displays the value returned by the function. which is in this case nothing. So undefined will be displayed.

Answer (score 4):

You are likely running this in the browser's console.  It is printing the returned value after calling `console.log()`.

[image: Console output]

`console.log()` returns `undefined`.  What `undefined` is is a whole other question.  Suffice it to say, with respect to this instance, it is the default value returned by a function that has no explicit `return` statement.

---

You asked:

> so basically every time i call a function that returns void (in this
>   case console.log()) i will get this evaluation, right? undefined.

Don't confuse `void` and `undefined`.  They are not the same.  You can't even return `void`, it's a keyword for an operator: [void operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/void).  If you try to return it, you'll get a syntax error.

If a function that you define does not provide an explicit `return`, it will return `undefined` by default:

```
function foo(){
    var a = 2 + 2;
}
var bar = foo(); // bar has the value "undefined"
```

`undefined` is rather ironic, because it is a special, defined value.  You can do comparisons with it, you can assign things to it, you can return it explicitly.  It is a special falsy value.

Comment: so basically every time i call a function that returns void (in this case console.log()) i will get this evaluation, right? undefined.

Answer (score 2):

You get an `undefined` because nothing is being `returned` from the JavaScript you are writing.

Even if you just write this in the console:

```
console.log('Bar');
```

You would see `undefined`;

However, if you ran this in the console

```
function returnSomething() {
    return 'Hello';
}
returnSomething();
```

You would see "Hello", and no longer see `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

In this instance, "undefined" just means that the script has finished running. It looks like your program does what it is supposed to do, it populates 'b' and the logs it to the console. When that is done, the script finishes itself and outputs "undefined" because it's done.

Comment: Not because "it's done", but because the last expression returned `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

When you execute things in the console, the result of every line you execute will be logged.

For example, if you run `var x = 5;` in the console, you will also see undefined. That is because there if no output for `var x = 5;`

After running that, if you run `x = 9;` in the console, you will see `9` after that line. This means that the output of `x = 9` is `9` (this is just a something that the creators of JavaScript decided, but useful to know).

Just like creating a variable does not output anything, if you call a function that does not return anything, you will see undefined printed as well.

`console.log` is a function that doesn't return anything, but it is a function that adds text to the console. So the first thing that you are seeing is the text that `console.log(b)` is outputting (your array) and the second line is the output of the function (undefined).

Hope this helps :)